# check $_GET request if isset by its key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this URL

```
www.domain.com/page.php?odor[type]=black&odor[shape]=cube
```

How do i check if the `$_GET` request `isset()` by the keys? just something like

```
if(isset($_GET['odor[type]'])){
    echo $odor['type']
}
```

Comment: your `isset()` makes no sense. Do `print_r($_GET);` to figure out why. Also what you expect `echo()` to display?

Comment: `$_GET['odor']` is an array. Read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and about [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets cause the value to be generated as an array, with the contents of the square brackets as keys of that array.

Test that the main value is set, and then test if it has the key you are looking for.

```
if (isset($_GET['odor']) && isset($_GET['odor']['type']) {
    echo htmlspecialchars( $_GET['odor']['type'] );
}
```

Comment: You don't need to chain two `isset`s, one will do.

Comment: What does this method called? The double brackets, Does the 2nd brackets works as the key for the array?

Comment: @AXAI — Yes. That's is what I said in the first sentence of the answer.